# Codename One parse4cn1 build error

Tags: java, codenameone, parse4cn1

My application build normally, but when I add the libraries `parse4cn1` the build fails

ios example of failure:

> CompileC
>   build/Main.build/Release-iphoneos/Main.build/Objects-normal/armv7/com_codename1_components_FileEncodedImageAsync_1.o
>   Main-src/com_codename1_components_FileEncodedImageAsync_1.m normal
>   armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler  cd
>   /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build7817864654456423022xxx/dist
>   export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII  export
>   PATH="/Applications/Xcode6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode6.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin"
>   /Applications/Xcode6.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -x objective-c -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O3 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk
>   -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -miphoneos-version-min=5.1.1 -iquote /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build7817864654456423022xxx/dist/build/Main.build/Release-iphoneos/Main.build/Main-generated-files.hmap
>   -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build7817864654456423022xxx/dist/build/Main.build/Release-iphoneos/Main.build/Main-own-target-headers.hmap
>   -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build7817864654456423022xxx/dist/build/Main.build/Release-iphoneos/Main.build/Main-all-target-headers.hmap
>   -iquote /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build7817864654456423022xxx/dist/build/Main.build/Release-iphoneos/Main.build/Main-project-headers.hmap
>   -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build7817864654456423022xxx/dist/build/Release-iphoneos/include
>   -I/Applications/Xcode6.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
>   -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build7817864654456423022xxx/dist/build/Main.build/Release-iphoneos/Main.build/DerivedSources/armv7
>   -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build7817864654456423022xxx/dist/build/Main.build/Release-iphoneos/Main.build/DerivedSources
>   -F/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build7817864654456423022xxx/dist/build/Release-iphoneos
>   -include /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.0.1-6A317/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/Main-Prefix-emlrvbeeugebypcdhsskhvroiczx/Main-Prefix.pch
>   -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build7817864654456423022xxx/dist/build/Main.build/Release-iphoneos/Main.build/Objects-normal/armv7/com_codename1_components_FileEncodedImageAsync_1.d
>   --serialize-diagnostics /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build7817864654456423022xxx/dist/build/Main.build/Release-iphoneos/Main.build/Objects-normal/armv7/com_codename1_components_FileEncodedImageAsync_1.dia
>   -c /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build7817864654456423022xxx/dist/Main-src/com_codename1_components_FileEncodedImageAsync_1.m
>   -o /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build7817864654456423022xxx/dist/build/Main.build/Release-iphoneos/Main.build/Objects-normal/armv7/com_codename1_components_FileEncodedImageAsync_1.o
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:  CompileC
>   build/Main.build/Release-iphoneos/Main.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CodenameOne_GLAppDelegate.o
>   Main-src/CodenameOne_GLAppDelegate.m normal armv7 objective-c
>   com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler  (1 failure)

I checked and the `procedimetos` the project wiki, and realized that the exact time that builds fail and the inclusion of lib `parse4cn1`.

Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Added missing tags for better responses. This:  `The following build commands failed: CompileC build/Main.build/Release-iphoneos/Main.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CodenameOne_GLAppDelegate.o` indicates the issue is in `CodenameOne_GLAppDelegate`. Search the error log for that file and you will see the actual error.

Answer (score 1):

Do you get those errors after including parse4cn1.cn1lib or did you also try to inject native code for push notification support into your build? I ask because the log you posted on [github](https://github.com/sidiabale/parse4cn1/issues/15#issuecomment-166990272) suggests that you tried injecting push notification code into your app delegate but you seem to have included the inline comments as well. Comments will cause build errors because the code is stripped of line breaks so the comments will not be parsed correctly.

To isolate the problem faster, I suggest you try compiling your app with the version of the parse4cn1 lib that doesn't include push notification support available in [release 2.0.1](https://github.com/sidiabale/parse4cn1/releases/tag/parse4cn1-2.0.1). Of course, be sure to remove any parse4cn1-related build hints before compiling. If that works, you can switch to the version that supports push (if you need it) and *carefully* add the hints *without comments*

Answer (score 1):

as I did not find the error, I redid the whole process and it worked, solved, thanks